# 'in' or 'at': I'm expecting life in/at university

Tags: prepositions, articles, british-english

Is **at university** more common than **in university**?

I wish to convey a meaning that I am expecting life in/at university, which one shall I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use "of", "in" and "at"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/when-to-use-of-in-and-at)

Comment: @Dronehinge - I don't think that's even close to a duplicate; it's "related" at best. As a matter of fact, the word _university_ is not even mentioned at that other question. To the O.P.: the issue here isn't really which is more _common_, but which is more _applicable_ to your context. Sometimes, the less common wording is the one you should use.

Comment: What dialect do you want to use?  I think American and British English differ here.

Comment: I want to use the British version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statistically, and cross-linguistically, *at university* is more commonly-used than *in university*. Here's some numbers:

- [British corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=40766653):

  - *at university/universities*: 504
  - *in university/universities*: 243
- [American corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40766654):

  - *at university/universities*: 1,166
  - *in university/universities*: 730
- [Web corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=40766655):

  - *at university/universities*: 12,132
  - *in university/universities*: 5,603

I wouldn't call any of these an overwhelming majority, so what's the difference?

Here's a clear case where you can't use *at*:

> - [... acquired a larger voice in university affairs ...](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/x4.asp?t=330&ID=450416)
> - [... some opinions are simply not acceptable in university life ...](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/x4.asp?t=3056&ID=3240147)

So, for the meaning of *in* that corresponds roughly to *in the course of*, you can't use *at*.

Answer (score 4):

In USA, for actual location, we use 
"*at the* university" 
or "*at {name of university;e.g. "Yale"*}.

For the sense of being a student for a period:

"I'm *in* college."
Or
"When I was *in* college" 
Or
"When I was *at* MSU..."

...  NOT ...
 "When I was in university..."
Or
"When I was *at* university..."

xxxxxxxx
Before you attend a university:

> "Are you planning to *go to* college?"
>   "Yes."
>   "Which one?"
>   "Michigan State. [University]"
>   (the word "university" is usually left out)
>   "So how do you think you'll like {life *at college*/college life}?"
>   "Sounds like fun."
>   "Do you think you'll do well *at* MSU?"
>   "Mostly. I didn't do well *in* high-school math; but {*at/in*} college, I won't have to take math."