# "in" or "at" with the word University

Tags: prepositions

I'm compiling a table comparing the usage of prepositions 'in' and 'at' with the word 'university' using example sentences. Which preposition would be best suited to the following sentence:

1. I'm in my third year **in** university.
2. I'm in my third year **at** university.

Explanations accompanying your answer would be much appreciated, and if possible, a rule of thumb non-native speakers can follow when choosing between 'in' and 'at'.

Comment: This is a usage that is likely to be different depending on where you are in the English-speaking world.  Neither of these would be common un the US (people would say, "...in college"), while in Canada, "...at university" is more common. I can't speak to the usage in the UK, Australia, etc.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I think "in University is more common in Canada but that just proves the point. I would ask "what year are you in?" "What year are you at?" sounds really weird to me. "I'm in university" means I'm enrolled. "I'm at [the] university" means that's your current location and you left out "the" for some reason.

Comment: In the UK we would usually use *at*. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Americans would be more likely to say *of college* or *of school* when talking about being at university here: "I'm in my junior year of college" = UK "I'm in my third year at uni".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['in' or 'at': I'm expecting life in/at university](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63248/in-or-at-im-expecting-life-in-at-university)